# A Javascript function inside of the window.addEventListener("load",function() is not defined - why?

Tags: javascript

I have this very simple Javascript function called Notice(). I want to access it only after the page is loaded (the Notice() function uses some other variables that are only available after the pages load is completed). The error is - "Notice() function is not defined."
Why is it not defined and how to make sure it is defined and working correctly when included insed of the window.addEventListener("load",function() function?

The whole code is below and JS fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/2cymjn8z/

```
<button id="L" type="button" onclick="Notice()">Submit</button>

  window.addEventListener("load",function(){

function Notice(){
alert('ok');
}

},false);
```

Comment: Because the function isn't defined until after the button is created

Comment: From where this `Notice` function is supposed to be call? `window.addEventListener` or through button click

Comment: Hm. I thought the function loads first and then should be available (I click on the button after the page is loaded). Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: The Notice() function should be called only when button is clicked.

Comment: The problem is scope, not timing. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function declarations are scoped to the function they are declared in. You will only ever be able to call `Notice` from within the anonymous load function. You can change this by explicitly putting `Notice` on the `window`:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  window.Notice = function () {
    alert('ok');
  }
}, false);
```

Or better yet, get rid of `addEventListener` and just declare the function. I don't see much reason for it in your current code:

```
function Notice () {
  alert('ok');
}
```

You can see both approaches working in this CodePen:

https://codepen.io/delventhalz/pen/rpYBjq

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of the html creating the button you can eliminate the explicit onClick event and add it in via js after the window is loaded:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  window.Notice = function () {
    alert('ok');
  }
  document.getElementById("L").onclick = Notice()
}, false);
```

Comment: I tried to update it but it seems not to alert.. https://jsfiddle.net/2cymjn8z/2/ - maybe there's some mistake I made?

Comment: You made the mistake of _calling_ Notice on line 5 (i.e. `... = Notice()`), when you just want to _reference_ it (i.e. `... = Notice`). Also, it looks like JSFiddle suppresses alerts, otherwise you would see the alert as soon as the page loaded. You can see it working here: https://codepen.io/delventhalz/pen/jYaEwq. Though I would recommend simplifying it like this: https://codepen.io/delventhalz/pen/ypPyoV.